# Meteor ; how to destroy the template in 0.8

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I Have a layout with two alternate templates :

```
<template name="MyLayout">

    {{#if myBoolean}}
        {{> template1}}
    {{else}}
        {{> template2}}
    {{/if}}

</template>
```

When I switch my boolean to true (initialized on false), `Template.template1.rendered = function () {};` is triggered. But when I switch it to false, the `Template.template1.destroyed` hook is not triggered. And when I switch it back to true, the `Template.template1.rendered` event is not triggered either.

The thing is that I use the `rendered` hook to start a few animations. So my template1 is displayed the first time I switch the boolean to true, but not on the following switches.

Before 0.8, the rendered event was called to much. Now it's a little bit to few. Is there an option or something I can use to destroy my template when it's not in the DOM anymore ?

---

BTW : to make it work, I still have the ugly solution of putting a helper in the middle of the template1. That helper will be called every time the template is added to the DOM ; so I can start my animations from there. But this is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MasterLayout is still there; only the child template has been destroyed. You  might be able to use the child template `rendered`/`destroyed` handlers. If the animation is only relevant to the parent template elements, you might be able to create an autorun function that starts the animations based on your reactive boolean variable. For example, assuming your boolean is a `Session` variable (though it will work with any reactive variable):

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  if (Session.get("myBoolean")) {
    // start animation
  }
});
```

Now any time you `Session.set("myBoolean", true)`, the animation will run.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did paste to quick. The listener is on the child template and not on the master layout. In the last version of Meteor, the templates are not destroyed anymore when they are removed from the DOM. They still exists in memory.

Comment: I tried to repro your issue, but the callbacks are working as expected for me. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/sbking/80d4adf987935a40cb58) I tested with on  0.8.1.1.

Comment: Well... you're right. I have to figure out what I messed up in my project. Thank you :)

Comment: (btw, the boolean is not exactly a boolean for me, it's a `currentUser` helper)